# Ubuntu 20.04 lags while multitasking

Tags: 20.04

When I use Ubuntu for a while it starts to lag, especially when I multitask.
It starts to lag and freeze, even when my RAM and CPU are not in one hundred percent use.

Comment: During a lag, run the `free` command and add the complete output [to your Question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1269031/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu needs about 2 GB of RAM to function properly. Use the `free -h` command to check how much RAM you have. If it is less than 2 GB, there's your problem.

It may also be an issue with the CPU. Ubuntu should have at least a 2 GHz dual core processor to run properly. Use `cat /proc/cpuinfo` to check your CPU information.

If it only happens while you are online, you probably have a faulty internet connection.

If you have plenty of RAM, a good processor, and a great internet connection, I don't know what to tell you.